# Template Function Overload Resolution with sfml vectors

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, sfml

I'm trying to write some operators for the sfml library's "sf::Vector2" template classes (which basically just contain an x and y parameter of the specified type). I need to implement the basic arithmetic operators regarding both "Vector-Vector" and "Vector-Scalar/Scalar-Vector" interactions. Here is an example of what I did so far (multiplication operator):

```
//multiply vectors
template<typename TResult, typename TLeft, typename TRight>
inline auto operator*(const sf::Vector2<TLeft>& lhs, const sf::Vector2<TRight>& rhs){
    return sf::Vector2<TResult>(lhs.x * rhs.x, lhs.y * rhs.y);
}
//multiply sf vector and scalar
template<typename VT, typename ST>
inline auto operator*(const sf::Vector2<VT>& vect, const ST& scalar) {
    return sf::Vector2<VT>(vect.x * scalar, vect.y * scalar);
}
template<typename VT, typename ST>
inline auto operator*(const ST& scalar, const sf::Vector2<VT>& vect) {
    return vect * scalar;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to invoke an operator, such as this:

```
sf::Vector2<int> v1, v2;
sf::Vector2<int> v3 = v1 * v2;
```

The second version of the such operator (the one involving the scalar) is used by the compiler and, as a consequence, an error is generated. I thought that this would not happen, and that the compiler would have considered the first version of the operator thanks to overload resolution (the function accepts two vectors instead of one vector and a generic type). What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your vector multiplication overload, the template parameter `TResult` cannot be deduced. You could solve this issue by using `std::common_type_t`:

```
template<typename TLeft, typename TRight>
inline auto operator*(const sf::Vector2<TLeft>& lhs, const sf::Vector2<TRight>& rhs){
    return sf::Vector2<std::common_type_t<TLeft, TRight>>(lhs.x * rhs.x, lhs.y * rhs.y);
}
```